# Specify alternative fallback paths for Symfony to find twig templates for bundles

Tags: symfony, twig

### Basic Question

**How can you make symfony look in non-standard directories to find the "best" (custom) Twig template to load for a bundle view?**

The Symfony docs say by default it looks in two locations to [override a Twig template](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates)

> When the AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index.html.twig is rendered, Symfony
>   actually looks in two different locations for the template:
>
> app/Resources/AcmeBlogBundle/views/Blog/index.html.twig
>   src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/views/Blog/index.html.twig

But this is discussing how you would override a vendor bundle. In my case, I have native bundles in my /src/ that I want to overwrite on a per Design Template or Client specific basis. It needs to look in:

```
Client:    /var/www/vhosts/{ID}/src 
Template:  /var/www/core/cms/src/Gutensite/TemplateBundle/Templates/Admin/src
```

**Twig Loader** has a convenient method to add paths:

```
$templatePath = '/var/www/core/cms/src/Gutensite/TemplateBundle/Templates/Admin/Resources/views';
$this->container->get('twig.loader')->prependPath($templatePath, 'template');
```

This allows me to register an alternative path to the template resources, so that I can render the template shell like this:

{% extends '@template/shell/shell.html.twig' %}

But what about when I want to overwrite a bundle template, e.g.

```
Original: /var/www/core/cms/src/Gutensite/MenuBundle/Resources/views/Menu.html.twig
Custom:   /var/www/core/cms/src/Gutensite/TemplateBundle/Templates/Admin/src/Gutensite/MenuBundle/Resources/views/Menu.html.twig
```

How do I register a generic /src/ file so that Symfony looks in there for all references to Vendor Bundle paths, e.g. trying to render `@GutensiteMenu/Menu.html.twig` will first look in the custom directory for **1) Client** , **2) Template**, 3) default bundle directory by that name.

### Need Assets

Because my TemplateBundle/Templates/Admin/Resources/ are in a non-standard location, assetic won't dump them to the public directory (or create symlinks)... so I'm not sure how to dynamically make assetic find these files.

I'm also not sure how to load the assets that are in these other locations, e.g. this doesn't work:

```
{% stylesheets '@GutensiteTemplateBundle/Templates/Admin/Resources/public/css/site.css' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Presumably because it's not dumped.

### Why do I need this?

I am building a hosted CMS that is a core vendor which contain various bundles with controllers and templates, e.g. `/Gutensite/CmsBundle`, `Gutensite/ArticleBundle`.

Based on the selected "Design Template" for a site, a design template is referenced in a TemplateBundle, e.g. `/TemplateBundle/Templates/Admin` (a template called "Admin"). The TemplateBundle need to be able to override the core controllers or views.

I have registered the Gutensite/TemplateBundle/Templates/Admin/src/ folder as an alternative namespace for the Composer app/autoload.php, so that controllers can be overwritten as long as they have the same `Gutensite` namespace (and this works great):

```
// in my primary controller:
$loader = $GLOBALS['loader'];
$loader->add('Gutensite', '/var/www/core/cms/src/Gutensite/TemplateBundle/Templates/Admin/src', true);
```

*NOTE: I could register every single template as a bundle, and that would theoretically allow me to override controllers and bundles using symfony's built in methods. But this would add a lot of "bundles" that aren't really traditional bundles. Also I need the above solution to point to alternative template paths, because I also need the ability to point to client's custom files located outside the normal symfony root directory (which I successfully do with the namespace auto loader paths for controllers).*

Comment: FYI, I ended up making a `Templates` vendor so each template is a bundle in that vendor. That solves one of the problems, by using the default inheritance methods. I also register the alternative paths to the custom client `/var/www/vhosts/999/src/` folder so that it looks in the client's files first. However, there are still issues with loading assets correctly. We'll probably overcome that with assets stored externally on a file server anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `path` option in the twig configuration, with the same namespace for 2 paths.

```
twig:
    # ...
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Gutensite/MenuBundle/Resources/views": templates
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Gutensite/TemplateBundle/Templates/Admin/src/Gutensite/MenuBundle/Resources/views": templates
```

Then, using `@templates/Menu.html.twig` will first look for `Menu.html.twig` in MenuBundle, then in TemplateBundle.

That's this way that the `TwigExtension` is registering paths so the loader is looking in `app/Resources/views` and then in the bundle's views.

Comment: Well the problem with hard coding the config is that this is a hosted CMS, so these need to be loaded dynamically. Fortunately, we can do that with the code I mentioned above: `$this->container->get('twig.loader')->prependPath($templatePath, 'template');` However, we still have issues with loading assets from that alternative location, which we will likely just overcome with full paths (to another file server).