# Symfony add default template search path

Tags: symfony, templates, twig, templating

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734764/specify-alternative-fallback-paths-for-symfony-to-find-twig-templates-for-bundle?s=2%7C0.2703) but slightly different and since that question wasn't answered, I thought I would try again.

I know Symfony will look first in `app/Resources/FooBundle/views` and then second in `FooBundle/Resources/views` for templates. I would like to "inject" another location between the two, e.g.

1. `app/Resources/FooBundle/views`
2. `BarBundle/Resources/FooBundle/views`
3. `FooBundle/Resources/views`

I've tried overriding the `\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Config\FileLocator` service and added a path there, but this didn't work. I've also tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050384/define-custom-filesystem-path-for-twig-templates) in the controller::render method without success. (the 'native' method suggested there doesn't work because the path comes from a dynamic setting.)

As a secondary note, I need to be able to add this path later (maybe onRequest) instead of at container creation. So an EventListener, custom service method or call in the controller would be appropriate.

Comment: Twig namespaces will allow you to do this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html though it requires some slight adjustments to how you specify your twig paths.  It's actually an improvement over the default approach.  Otherwise, take a look at how Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\DependencyInjection\TwigExtenstion; sets the paths.  It's possible to do the same sort of thing in your BarBundle extension but it's been too long since I did it.  Can't provide a useful example.

Comment: Thank you for responding Cerad. I had previously looked at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html and indeed it seems like a good solution except I cannot see how to dynamically assign namespaces. e.g. I could not see how to assign a *service* instead of *strings* or later assign a namespace (in the controller or something). Secondly, I couldn't understand TwigExtension. Maybe if you can find an example :D

Comment: Sorry.  Been too long since I dug into the internals.  Seldom even use twig anymore.  I really don't see a need for services etc.  I would suggest adjusting your design to fit twig's native capabilities or move on to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the challenge in solving this problem was realizing that (at least in Symfony 2.7) there are at least two ways to specify a template name: the 'old way' (for lack of a better name) and the 'name-spaced' method which was implemented later. e.g.

```
class MyController extends \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller
{
    // the 'old way'
    public function barAction()
    {
        return $this->render('FooBundle:User:foo.html.twig');
    }
    // namespaced
    public function fooAction()
    {
        return $this->render('@Foo/User/foo.html.twig');
    }
}
```

These two methods result in different template location searches and therefore code had to be modified in two different places.

In order to modify the 'old' way, I overrode the Kernel::locateResource() method

```
public function locateResource($name, $dir = null, $first = true)
{
    $customBundle = $this->container->get('my_custom_bundle');
    $locations = parent::locateResource($name, $dir, false);
    if ($locations && (false !== strpos($locations[0], $dir))) {
        // if found in $dir (typically app/Resources) return it immediately.
        return $locations[0];
    }

    // add custom path to template locator
    // this method functions if the controller uses `@Template` or `FooBundle:Foo:index.html.twig` naming scheme
    if ($customBundle && (false === strpos($name, $customBundle->getName()))) {
        // do not add override path to files from same bundle
        $customPath = $customBundle->getPath() . '/Resources';
        return parent::locateResource($name, $customPath, true);
    }
    return $locations[0];
}
```

In order to modify the namespace way, I added a ControllerListener

```
class OverrideListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $loader;
    private $customBundle;

    function __construct(\Twig_Loader_Filesystem $loader, $customBundle)
    {
        $this->loader = $loader;
        $this->customBundle = $customBundle;
    }

    /**
     * @param FilterControllerEvent $event
     * @throws \Twig_Error_Loader
     */
    public function setUpOverrides(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        // add custom path to template locator
        // This 'twig.loader' functions only when @Bundle/template (name-spaced) name-scheme is used
        $controller = $event->getController()[0];
        if ($controller instanceof AbstractController) {
            $bundleName = $controller->getName(); // my AbstractController adds a getName method returning the BundleName
            if ($this->customBundle) {
                $overridePath = $this->customBundle->getPath() . '/Resources/' . $bundleName . '/views';
                if (is_readable($overridePath)) {
                    $paths = $this->loader->getPaths($bundleName);
                    // inject overridePath before the original path in the array
                    array_splice($paths, count($paths) - 1, 0, array($overridePath));
                    $this->loader->setPaths($paths, $bundleName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => array(array('setUpOverrides')),
        );
    }
}
```

I hope this helps anyone coming along looking for a similar solution.